# Code wars: Sign up issue

Tags: java

Im very new to programming and I recently tried to sign up to code wars. It shows a number of problems, presumably before letting someone sign up.

At the minute I'm stuck on this one:

```
public class Person{
    String name;

    public Person(String personName){
        name = personName;
    }

    public String greet(String yourName){
        return String.format("Hi %s, my name is %s", yourName, name);
    }
}
```

Stating Correct this code, so that the greet function returns the expected value.

I can't for the life of me figure out what the problem is. I tried inputing the code into eclipse and there are no errors, so I'm not entirely sure what is required

Comment: Look the orders of the parameters in the format function.

Comment: well running it in the "IDE" on the site just returns the generic error "The code does not work as expected". Could it possibly be an assignment issue?

Comment: This question is off-topic because it's about explaining instructions.

Comment: To me the instructions are somewhat vague, and I can;t seem to find anywhere where the problem is discussed. I expect it to return a String, which it does, But I don't know if that is what is expected

Comment: I have provided the answer. Also I think you're looking into it too much. It seems fairly ambiguous but it's basic logic and gets you to read code properly.

Comment: I see, I think I understand what was asked now, Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it wants you to greet someone else.

```
public class Person{
String name;

public Person(String personName){
    name = personName;
}

public String greet(String yourName){
    return String.format("Hi %s, my name is %s", name, yourName);
}
}
```

So that the output is

Hi (person), my name is (whatever your name is)

Comment: */facepalm* well, that was a nice half-hour i wasted. i cant believe I didn't spot that.

Answer (score 5):

Seriously, that was a waste of time. I had the same issue, there is nothing related to finding errors, it just wants to greet you. So just swap the arguments(name,yourName) in return statement.

Answer (score 2):

The Answer Is : Justyou need two swap the variables in String.format().

Question:

return String.format("Hi %s, my name is %s", **name**, **yourName**);

Answer :

return String.format("Hi %s, my name is %s", **yourName**, **name**);

```
     public class Person
     {
         String name;
         public Person(String personName){
         name = personName;
         }
         public String greet(String yourName)
          {
             return String.format("Hi %s, my name is %s", yourName,name);
           }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

As it mentioned, the compiler expects a certain String as following,

```
public class Person{
String name;

public Person(String personName){
    name = personName;
}

public String greet(String yourName){
    return String.format("Hi %s, my name is %s", "Kate", "Joe");
}
}
```